# Переопрделение классов в дочерней теме wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Имеется тема вордпрес которая использует файлы php в дирректории `inc/..`

Каким образом например можно переопределить в дочерней теме  класс из деректории `inc/integrations/wp-job-manager-resumes/`

Answer (score 0):

Если в этом файле функция проверяется на наличие - скопировать её в файл функций дочки вместе с проверкой и изменить как нужно.

Если же нет - создать свою функцию со своим уникальным именем, а там где вызывается родительская - заменить на вызов своей.